# PHP explode doesn't work

Tags: php, web-development-server

I have a text file and I want each line to be an element of an array.

```
$file = file("books.txt");
$split = explode("\n", $file);
```

Then if I try to print an element of the array:

```
echo "$split[0]";
```

I get no output.

Comment: `file` add a dollar sign; `split1` remove the 1; also what is the output of: `print_r($file);` ?

Comment: Fixed that. Thank you. It works as n-dru said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `file("books.txt")` gives already an array resulting from exploding by newline, you can `echo "$file[0]";`, no need for further exploding.